# Modern data structures

Tags: data-structures

I just realized all the data structures I regularly use are really old and really simple. Linked lists, hash tables, trees, and even the more complex variants such as VLists or RBTrees are all pretty old inventions.

Most of them were conceived for a serial, single CPU world and require adapting to work in parallel environments.

What kind of newer, better data structures do we have? Why are they not widely used?

I understand using a plain old linked list if you have to *implement* it and prefer the simplicity, but having huge STLs and piles of third party libraries like *Guava* or *Boost*, why am I still placing locks around hashes?

Don't we have potentially standard, hard-proven modern data structures that can actually *replace* the trusty old-timers?

Comment: Because there's nothing wrong with the old ones? And if it ain't broke, don't fix it?

Comment: There was nothing *wrong* with the Z80 either. Luckily, it was "fixed".

Comment: What precisely are you expecting from new data structures? Synchronization for instance is a an implementation detail, it's not *per se* part of the data structure. Besides, purely functional data structures don't need locks as they are not mutated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the old ones. A good way to keep flexibility is to separate concerns. Normal (old style) datastructures are concerned with the way how data is stored. Locking is a completely different concern, which should not be part of the datastructure.

Locking is a potentially expensive operation, so if you can, you should lock multiple structures at once to optimize your code. I.e. lock critical sections not datastructures. If you directly add locking to your datastructures, you do not have the possibility to optimize this way. Also this will introduce implicit synchronisation points, that you may not want and canot control.

This does not answer a different aspect of your question. The part of "Why do we need locking at all". The answer is, that sometimes there is just no way around it. You either need to have lock somewhere, completely rely on atomic operations or disallow mutation altogether.

Method one is not feasible, as I have pointed out above, because you loose potential for optimization and you have implicit synchronisation points.

Only using atomic operations in your data structure (i.e. non-locking structures) is still an open research question, and might not always be possible. I know of some non-locking structures, i.e. queues, lists etc, but I have never heard of a non locking tree. Also non-locking structures tend to become much more complicated and slower, so we still need some better structure for thread local data, and can only add these to our datastructure zoo.

Not having mutable datastructures at all is in my opinion the best way of all of them. Mutability is often more of a hassle than it is worth. However this is a concept from functional programming and only makes sense in such an environment. Functional programming however is regarded as an esoteric concept by most programmers. Most languages which are actually used in production work mainly use non-functional concepts (this does not mean it actually is more complicated or is more error prone, it is just reflecting the current state of training among developers). In my opinion functional programming will become more wide spread, once people start to note it solves their threading problems automatically in a blink. Several other languages are now borrowing already from functional languages, so this is probably where we will find the next evolution of data structures.

Comment: -1 for the rant against FP and the nonsensical statement that immutable structures make no sense outside it.

Comment: @larsmans: Where do you see a rant against FP? Read closer. I am a big proponent **for** FP, so you'll not see a rant against it from me. What I was stating is the fact that FP is not widely used. Have a look at TIOBE for a indication at usage. LISP is the first FP-language to appear in the 2012 and 2011 ranking and comes in at place 15. Haskell, OCaml, Erlang, Clojure come in much later only. Most programmers do not know how FP works, and most companies do not use it. This is a fact, but this has nothing to do with the notion whether FP is a good idea or not (I think it is a good idea).

Comment: @larsmans: The question wether immutable data structures are of much use outside of FP however is a different one altogether, I agree. Of the programmers I know of only about 10% know how to use FP at all. Most of them from python and other languages which have adopted it, but are not pure. Only about 5% actually can get along in it. Taking the mutability away will render most programmers absolutely helpless, so it simply is a bad idea for now. This is not a rant against immutability, but against programmers, who never cared to look at anything outside of their domain, which are most of them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want lock-free data structures, study [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). These are mostly popular in the functional programming world, but are applicable in other domains as well. Most persistent DSs are variants of plain lists, trees etc. but newer ones such as [hash tries](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/09/08/understanding-clojures-persistenthashmap-deftwice/) have surfaced in recent years.